# Read output from InvokeAscmd in azure automation PowerShell runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, mdx, azure-analysis-services

I want to read the output of last refreshed time of a AAS tabular table and then send an email if the refresh was successful on the current day.

Below MDX query is being used to fetch the same
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7SgX.png]

While running the same Query through below powershell script -

```
$AzureCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "AzOps.Azure.Group.PROD.EDAP.SA"

$database = "SCP"
$Query = @"
SELECT RefreshedTime
FROM $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS
where TableID=10
"@

$result=(Invoke-ASCmd ` -ServicePrincipal ` -Credential $Azurecred ` -TenantId "95e66ecc-f2c2-464b-84d9-8fda407bc923" ` -Server "asazure://westeurope.asazure.windows.net/asedapprodscp" ` -Database "$database" ` -Query $Query ` -Confirm:$False)

echo $result
```

Following is the output -

```
<return xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis"><root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:mddataset" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset" xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><xsd:element name="root"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xsd:element name="row" type="row" /></xsd:sequence></xsd:complexType></xsd:element><xsd:simpleType name="uuid"><xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"><xsd:pattern value="[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{12}" /></xsd:restriction></xsd:simpleType><xsd:complexType name="xmlDocument"><xsd:sequence><xsd:any /></xsd:sequence></xsd:complexType><xsd:complexType name="row"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element sql:field="RefreshedTime" name="RefreshedTime" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0" /></xsd:sequence></xsd:complexType></xsd:schema><row xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset"><RefreshedTime>2023-10-12T09:57:32.556667</RefreshedTime></row></root></return>
```

How do I fetch the RefreshedTime from this ??
Tried converting output to XML as well getting below -
updated Script -

```
$AzureCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "AzOps.Azure.Group.PROD.EDAP.SA"

$database = "SCP"
$Query = @"
SELECT RefreshedTime
FROM $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS
where TableID=10
"@

$result=[xml](Invoke-ASCmd ` -ServicePrincipal ` -Credential $Azurecred ` -TenantId "95e66ecc-f2c2-464b-84d9-8fda407bc923" ` -Server "asazure://westeurope.asazure.windows.net/asedapprodscp" ` -Database "$database" ` -Query $Query ` -Confirm:$False)

echo $result.return.root.row.Name
```

Output -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your workaround is valid till you convert it into `XML`. However,
when retrieving refreshed time, you need to capture it as `$result.root.row.RefreshedTime`. It gives you access to and displays the `Refreshed Time` value as shown.

```
$TenantId= "xxxxx"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$AplicationId ="xxxxx"
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AplicationId , $Password)
$database = "xxxdata"
$Query = @"
SELECT Refreshedtime
FROM $SYSTEM.table_jahn
where TableID=1
"@
$result=[xml](Invoke-ASCmd -ServicePrincipal -Credential $psCred -TenantId $TenantId -Server "jahnserver.database.windows.net" -Database $database -Query $Query -Confirm:$False)
$refreshedTime = $result.root.row.Refreshedtime
Write-Host "$refreshedTime"
```

[image]

*Try the same script in Automation runbook to achieve your requirement.*